# Siri Suggested Websites favicon

Tags: ios, safari, meta-tags, favicon, siri

I am having trouble finding the answer to including an icon in "Siri Suggested Websites" on iPhone's Safari. Is there a line of code that I can use to achieve this?

[image: Siri Suggested Website]

I've tried:
`<link href="/home_badge_64.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />`
`<link rel="mask-icon" href="/favicon.svg" color="#990000">`

in my header tags as well as clearing out my cache and restarting my phone

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has been searching for a solution, I was able to find an answer to this. Apparently, it pulls from the og meta tags, but only after your site is reindexed. So, it won't show up immediately. Here is an example:

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="“600”">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="“400”">
<meta property="og:title" content="Your Title">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com/">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.com/featured-image.jpg">
```